# Sending bytes to bluetooth device

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using the flutter package flutter_reactive_ble to communicate with a ble device and for now I'm able to scan for it, and connect to it. I managed to create some methods to convert and send bytes but for some reason I'm not getting the expected response from the device. I know there is not much documentation and there is a lack of examples and people actually getting the help they needed but I'll try either way in case some of you is an expert with IoT.

I'm currently sending commands that are in hex and I convert them decimal so the device can actually interpret these values. All happening here:

```
  //HEADERS
  List<String> _header_1 = ['46', '4D', '42', '58'];
  List<String> _header_2 = ['4d', '4b', '49', '53'];

  //COMMANDS TO SEND
  List<String> _cmdALL = ['00', '02'];
  List<String> _cmdINF = ['00', '1c'];
  List<String> _cmdGPS = ['00', '1e'];
  List<String> _cmdGSM = ['00', '20'];
  List<String> _cmdIO = ['00', '22'];
  List<String> _cmdOBD = ['00', '24'];
  List<String> _cmdCAN = ['00', '26'];
```

sending data:

```
Uuid _UART_UUID = Uuid.parse("6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
Uuid _UART_RX = Uuid.parse("6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");
Uuid _UART_TX = Uuid.parse("6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E");   

List<int> bytes = [];

void _parseData() {
    bytes = []; //RESETS BYTES

    _concatenatedMessage.map((e) {
      var intValue = int.tryParse(e, radix: 16);
      bytes.add(intValue!);
    }).toList();
  }

void _sendData(header, cmd, tx) {
    try {
      _concatenateMessage(header, cmd);
      _parseData();
      print('Parsed data: $bytes');

      flutterReactiveBle.writeCharacteristicWithResponse(_txCharacteristic,
          value: bytes);
    
      print('Sent Data');
      print('$bytes');
      _sentDataLog = "${_sentDataLog} $bytes\n";

      refreshScreen();
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print("Couldn't Send Data");
    }
  }
```

concatenate message:

```
void _concatenateMessage(header, cmd) {
    _concatenatedMessage = header + cmd;
  }
```

data received:

```
  void onNewReceivedData(List<int> data) {
    _numberOfMessagesReceived += 1;
    _receivedData
        .add("$_numberOfMessagesReceived: ${String.fromCharCodes(data)}");
    if (_receivedData.length > 5) {
      _receivedData.removeAt(0);
    }
    refreshScreen();
  }
```

on connection with the device:

```
final _txCharacteristic = QualifiedCharacteristic(
          serviceId: _UART_UUID,
          characteristicId: _UART_TX,
          deviceId: event.deviceId,
        );

        _sendData(_header_1, _cmdALL, _txCharacteristic);
        _sendData(_header_1, _cmdINF, _txCharacteristic);
        _sendData(_header_1, _cmdGPS, _txCharacteristic);
        _sendData(_header_1, _cmdGSM, _txCharacteristic);
        _sendData(_header_1, _cmdIO, _txCharacteristic);
        _sendData(_header_1, _cmdOBD, _txCharacteristic);
        _sendData(_header_1, _cmdCAN, _txCharacteristic);
```

Data being sent looks like this: [70, 77, 66, 88, 0, 38]

Expected response should also be a string of bytes giving me the data in which the device was configured to send.

I'm not the one who programmed the device although I'm getting based on the previous app that successfully got a response from it but it was made in Xamarin.

So my question is, how come I'm not getting a response? What could have I done wrong or what could be missing?

Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete example. The above code does not compile and is missing essential pieces (eg. how ‘bytes’ is defines and created). There also seems to be a mixup of RX and TX characteristics.

Comment: I'm just following [this example](https://github.com/wolfc01/flutter_reactive_ble_uart_example/blob/master/lib/main.dart). I edited the code to show how the bytes are defined.

Comment: ‘_sendData’ has two parameters but is called with three?! And the data is written to an RX characteristic?!

Comment: yeah I got a bit confused there, sorry. I think it's fixed now

Comment: Please create a complete example that shows what _header_1, _cmdXXX is, what _concatenateMessage does, how the instance variables are declared etc.

Comment: should me better now. lmk if anything is missing

Comment: While the code is unnecessarily complex, there is no obvious bug. Are you sure you are sending to the correct bytes to the correct characteristics? Are you getting any responses at all? Without additional information about the Bluetooth device, it's not really possible to provide additional help.